# Извините, этот тип файла недопустим по соображениям безопасности

Tags: wordpress, шрифты, wordpress-плагины, mime-type

Как исправить ошибку?

> Извините, этот тип файла недопустим по соображениям безопасности.

Пытаюсь загрузить файл eot, как требует тема для подключения кастомного фонта (woff, tff грузятся корректно в медиа). 
Пробовал: [плагины](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-mime-types/), [правку function.php](http://pronets.ru/izvinite-dannyj-tip-fajlov-zapreshhen-iz-soobrazhenij-bezopasnosti/), [правку wp-config.php](https://www.hostinger.ru/rukovodstva/oshibka-bezopasnosti-izvinite-etot-tip-fayla-nedopustim#gref)

- WordPress 4.9.8
- php 7.2
- nginx 1.12

Comment: Ну не в медиа-библиотеку же грузить шрифт. Они обычно заливаются по ftp в подпапку темы. Кроме того, eot вам зачем? Его никто, кроме IE не читает. Используйте woff, woff2.

Comment: Вдруг человек хочет делиться шрифтами на своем сайте? Попробуйте это - https://gist.github.com/robwent/e3bf00bafe7a00bc3d0c4dceabde4fca